# textfile line reader- java

Tags: java, arraylist, text-files, bufferedreader

```
    ArrayList <Integer> referenceNom = new ArrayList <Integer>();
    ArrayList <String> bookTitle = new ArrayList <String>();
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Booklist.txt"));
        while ((br.readLine()) != null ){
            for (int count = 1; count <= 44; count++){
                if (count % 2 == 1){
                    referenceNom.add(Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()));
                    System.out.print(referenceNom.get(count));
                }else {
                    bookTitle.add(br.readLine());
                    System.out.print(bookTitle.get(count));
                }
            }                                     
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to create a reader that reads the lines of a text file, which in this case is "Booklist.txt". The problem is I keep on getting an java.lang.NumberFormatException error. The text file consists of 44 lines and on the first line it's a number, the second line is a book title, the third is a number again and so on. I tried to create a reader that checks if the line number is even or odd and depending on that would add that line of text to either an integer arraylist or string arraylist. Integer arraylist for the numbers and string arraylist for the book title. Also I tried to keep track of the line number by creating a counter that adds 1 to count everytime a line is read.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: `} else if (count == 1); {` is wrong. You could just drop a conditional and use `else`.

Comment: edited that part thanks

Comment: Don't use the  if and else if statement, just have the BufferedReader read one line, then right after read the second line. This will cut your for-loop code down to 2 lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You "throw away" the first line. Therefore you get the first title first, not the first number. You should use only 1 loop, not the while loop and the for loop:

```
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null ){
    referenceNom.add(Integer.parseInt(line));
    bookTitle.add(br.readLine());                 
}
```

or

```
for (int count = 1; count <= 44; count++){
     if (count % 2 == 1){
         referenceNom.add(Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()));
     } else {
         bookTitle.add(br.readLine());
     }
 }
```

should work.

Comment: Yeah I tried the first code and it worked. How come you created String line? Can't i just use br.readLine() like it was used to add the string to bookTitle?

Comment: @JeffreyCaoWatsYourPowerLvl: I thought you wanted to keep the numbers. Every call of `readLine` reads a different line. If you don't assign the return value to a variable, you'll loose that information. You need to store the result in a variable, since you want to do 2 things with the result: a) check for `null` to determine, if the end of file is reached b) parse the line and add the result to the list.

Comment: yeah I do want to keep the numbers just trying to understand why you did stuff :). I meant like how come to add to referenceNom you did .add(line) but for bookTitle you did .add(br.readLine). Does bookTitle.add(line) not work?

Comment: @JeffreyCaoWatsYourPowerLvl: `line` always contains the line with the number. If there is line with a number, for correct input files a line with the title follows. You don't need to check again, if the end of the file is reached after the number line. Therefore the return value of the `readLine` call is directly passed to the `add` method of the list. (The while loop reads **both lines in the same iteration**.)

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0;
String line = null;
while (line = (br.readLine() != null)) {
    if (count % 2 == 0) {
        referenceNom.add(Integer.parseInt(line));
    } else {
        bookTitle.add(line);
    }
    count++;
}
```

Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, store the readed line on a Variable

```
String line=br.readLine();
```

Then you can use a Try-Cach to identify the kind of value, so your code might be like this:

```
String line=null;
while ((line=br.readLine()) != null ){
         try{
              referenceNom.add(Integer.parseInt(line));
              System.out.print(referenceNom.get(count));
         }catch(java.lang.NumberFormatException e){
             bookTitle.add(line);
             System.out.print(bookTitle.get(count));
        }catch(Exception e){
            //Unexpected Exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }                                     
    }
```

And like this, there could be more or less lines than 44 and you won't need to change your code

Comment: This has the same problem described by @fabian. You discard the first line in the condition of the while loop.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to change the pasted code of Integer.pasreInt... @ReubenSanders

Comment: The problem is still there in the while loop condition: `(br.readLine()) != null`

Comment: i feel like a rookie... im sorry @ReubenSanders